# Linear transformation + Rank & Nullity

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If $$T : \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^3$$ is a linear transformation which is defined by $$T(a,b,c,d) = (a-b+c+d, a+2c-d, a+b+3c-3d)$$ then verify $$Rank(T) + Nullity(T) = dim \mathbb{R}^4.$$

Comment: write the matrix and reduce it to echelon form and find the rank...and nulity=dim-rank..use it

Answer (score 1):

$T(a,b,c,d)=0$ implies $a (1,2,0,1)=(a,b,c,d) $ for all  $(a,b,c,d)\in N(T) $.Those two vectors are linearly independent and generates  $N (T) $.Hence has dimension $1$.Consider the standard ordered basis ${e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4} $ ... (we could choose any basis,just for simplicity I choose it). $T(e_1)=(1,1,1);T(e_2)=(-1,0,1);T(e_3)=(1,2,3),T(e_4)=(1,-1,-3)$ generates image of $T $. $rank (T)=3$ .
Hence...$rank T + nullity T=4=dimR^4$